# Using WHERE clause dynamically in select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get a particular `user_id` and `balance` using a `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause from user input

This is my trigger in SQL Server 2008:

```
create trigger trig_trans
on user_accnt after update
as
begin
    declare @id int
    declare @balance int
    declare @transdate date

    select @id = user_id, @balance = user_bal 
    from user_accnt

    merge user_trans target
    using user_accnt source on target.user_id = source.user_id

    when matched then
       update set trans_date = getdate(),
                  balance = @balance

    when not matched then
       insert (user_id, trans_date, balance)
       values(@id, getdate(), @balance);
end
```

In this `SELECT` statement, I want to use a `WHERE` clause.

```
select @id = user_id, @balance = user_bal 
from user_accnt
```

For example : if I am using

```
select @id = user_id, @balance = user_bal 
from user_accnt 
where account_num = 123456
```

I will get the result.

But in my situation my query should get the `account_num` from the user input.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's no way to pass user input into a trigger - unless you're storing that user input in that very table the trigger is operating on

Comment: Yes the user input is being stored in user_accnt table under the column account_num. @marc_s

Comment: So your trigger should be referencing the `inserted` or `deleted` tables.